# XAMPP ( Apache ) randomly stops working - "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

Tags: apache, google-chrome, xampp

So here's my situation:

I have a small website with minimal server load however on a seemingly random basis when clicking links chrome gives me the "Webpage not available" screen. Normally refreshing the page fixes the issue, i'm not sure why or how this happens.

Sometimes instead of Webpage not available it will just load forever until I refresh.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT #1 :
    This has been a problem for me on my home network and on my phone ( with WiFi off and mobile data used )

Comment: Can you check from separate network internally and externally.

Comment: This has been a problem for me on my home network and on my phone ( with WiFi off and mobile data used )